# Why is this function overloading not working in solidity?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

i'm new into Solidity and i was just messing around creating smart contracts using hardhat as my development environment. The thing is, i found out that solidity allows function overloading as long as parameters defer from type and/or number arguments.

Once i knew it, i decided to give it a try. I have the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {
    string message;
    uint256 totalWaves;
    
    constructor() {
        console.log("Smart contract constructor");
    }

    function wave(string memory _message) public {
        message = _message;
        console.log("%s has waved!", msg.sender);
    }

    function wave() public {
        totalWaves += 1;
        console.log("%s has waved! version no parameters", msg.sender);
    }
}
```

To test the code, i have a hardhat script that compiles and deploys the contract and calls the functions. This is the code:

```
const main = async () => {
    const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
    const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
    await waveContract.deployed();
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", waveContract.address);

    let waveTxn = await waveContract.wave("Hello world");
    await waveTxn.wait();
};

  const runMain = async () => {
    try {
      await main();
      process.exit(0); // exit Node process without error
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1); // exit Node process while indicating 'Uncaught Fatal Exception' error
    }
    // Read more about Node exit ('process.exit(num)') status codes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163396/7974948
};
  
runMain();
```

However, when compiling solidity tells me that wave is not a function:

```
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
Smart contract constructor
Contract deployed to: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
TypeError: waveContract.wave is not a function
```

The funny thing is that if i rename one wave function (removing the function overloading) it works. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem with Solidity, Solidity supports overloaded functions alright. It's a problem with Javascript. Javascript does not support overloaded functions.

So, to let your `ethersjs` contract instance know which Solidity function to call, you will need to use the full typed signature of the functions when calling it.

To call the `wave(string)` function from js, do:

```js
let waveTxn = await waveContract["wave(string)"]("Hello world");
```

To call the `wave()` function from js, do:

```js
let waveTxn = await waveContract["wave()"]();
```

Check the docs: https://docs.ethers.io/v3/api-contract.html